# Why do so many programmers imports `useState` separately, whereas it would be just as workable to simply use `React.useState`?

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I am curious as to why so many programmers import `useState` separately.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
const [foo, setFoo] = useState('foo');
```

Whereas, wouldn't it be easier on the memory to just import react and do `React.useState`?

```
import React from 'react';
const [foo, setFoo] = React.useState('foo');
```

Comment: When you're using just once doesn't look such improvement, but you can use more times. Also, the code is cleaner.

Comment: @GabrielFerrari Oh surely that can't be the main reason, can it? Coders type and call various methods from objects all the time... Why would they want to save on this particular method at the expense of performance... Even if it's just a little bit? I don't get it...

Comment: `useState` is a reference to a function, it doesn't store the actual function value itself. It will point to the same function in memory which `React.useState` points to in memory, so destructuring like this won't impact memory much, and it saves the programmer from needing to continouly keep writing the `React` prefix

Comment: @NickParsons Aah okay. Thank you for the insight. It makes sense now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some of us have different preferences. It's tab vs spaces basically. I like to use `React.use` wherever the hooks are.
So if I were to delete the hook from the file, I could do it in that line and should not worry about the unused imports.

Comment: I like that... :)

Answer (score 1):

When I'm prototyping, I use `React.useState` because it's quicker to type without having to wait for the IDE to auto import for me. Later on if I have more time and know that the code won't change much anymore, I may refactor to use `useState` or `useEffect` because it looks cleaner

Also when I write reusable hooks, I will use `useHook` separately because it looks simpler and I know that I won't touch the code for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Destructuring is one of good features in ES6 syntax comparing with vanilla Javascript.
It makes code more short, clean and readable.
And many developers are following this updated feature in ES6 in coding.

In React programming, developers enjoy writing code with Desructuring feature rather than referring sub property with parent object.

So I'd like to say Destructuring has became one common rule in perspective of code formatting in most Javascript programming.

And this Destructuring feature is widely used in exporting and importing modules in javascript.

So to unify coding pattern in whole project, developers are choosing choice to import useState directly from react.

As well, in most cases, we use several states in React component which means that we need to use useState multiply. So it will also reduce repetition of using "React".

[Here](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/5-tips-to-write-better-react-code-a5bca3f9531c) is article which would be helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you. That was an interesting perspective. Although, I am not exactly sure I am convinced by the argument "reduce repetition of using React". It would just be inversely proportional to an increase in import statements... Obviously, adding to the overall number of lines in the codebase.